# Run kubernetes directly on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, virtual-machine

I got a VPS server running ubuntu, which is technically simply a VM. Now I thought about hosting a cluster on that VM instead of using AWS. So I would need to run the cluster directly on ubuntu.

One solution would be to simply use minikube which initializes another VM on top. But I'd prefer to run the kubernetes cluster directly on the VM.

As I am pretty new to all these topics I have no idea how to start at all. I'd guess I need a cluster management tool such as kops (which is used for AWS).

**Is it possible to run a kubernetes cluster directly on ubuntu?** 
Would be glad if you can help me getting started.

Answer (score 2):

Microk8s from Ubuntu makes this easy, or check out Kind from sig-testing.

Answer (score 2):

You can download kubeadm,kubectl and kubelet.
Then you can install k8s master using kubeadm init

PLease refer the below link
https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/ubuntu/

Answer (score 2):

MicroK8s by ubuntu will let you create cluster on single machine. Please have a look at the following blog for step by step instructions:

https://itnext.io/a-local-kubernetes-with-microk8s-33ee31d1eed9